# php check month exist between two dates

Tags: php, datetime

I have code to check whether the given date is in the range of two dates.

```
$paymentDate = strtotime("2014-02-10 00:00:00");

$contractDateBegin = strtotime("2014-01-01 00:00:00");
$contractDateEnd = strtotime("2014-02-16 00:00:00");

if (($paymentDate > $contractDateBegin) && ($paymentDate < $contractDateEnd))
{
 echo "is between";
}
else
{
 echo "NO GO!";  
}
```

But I need to know a month is in the range of two dates.
Here we have only month and year.
Here I am converting given date to unix time stamp and comparing the values to check the result. In the case if we don't have date then how to check is my question.

Comment: What happens if part of the month overlaps with the start or end date?

Comment: So what is it doing now?

Comment: Your second line is unnecessary. Remove it.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't understand what you need to know.

Comment: @JohnConde it's also an error.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* this is what you're looking for:

```
$month             = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m', '2010-05');
$contractDateBegin = (new DateTime('01/01/2001'))->modify('last day of this month')->setTime(23, 59, 59);
$contractDateEnd   = (new DateTime('01/01/2012'))->setTime(0, 0, 0);
if ($month > $contractDateBegin && $month < $contractDateEnd) {
    // The whole month is in between 
}
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/190764)

Comment: You need to show a sample value that you will be working with. That way we don't have to guess at what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

`$paymentDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', "2013-05-25 00:00:00");`

```
$contractDateBegin = date_create_from_format('Y-m-d', "2012-01-01 00:00:00");
$contractDateEnd = date_create_from_format('Y-m-d', "2014-01-01 00:00:00");
if (($paymentDate > $contractDateBegin) && ($paymentDate < $contractDateEnd))
{
month is between
}
```